# Making a DVDplayer playable DVD in ubuntu

Tags: dvd

I wanted to burn some home videos for my grandmother.
However I can not seem to do this in ubuntu.
I was recommended DeVeDe but I am not able to find it in the software center and the download link on their webpage is broken...
Does anyone know how I can make a DVD from an MKV that is playable on a standard DVD player? Would be greatly appreciated.
I searched this Forum and found no answer (other than DeVeDe which I can not find anywhere)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the webpage for DeVeDeNG: http://www.rastersoft.com/programas/devede.html

Answer (score 0):

Most DVD players support video files on a DVD in .avi format (MPEG-4/MPEG-2 video and mp3 audio). Some have limit of resolution ~720p.

And now some newer players support more video formats, like AVI, MKV,  WMV,  AVCHD,  MPO, Xvid, DivxHD, etc.

Try out some files on your DVD player. (Some DVD players have USB port also.)

**You can just convert the formats in Avidemux etc. and write the files directly to DVD.**

> **Write files to a CD or DVD**
>
> You can put files onto a blank disc by using CD/DVD Creator. The option to create a CD or DVD will appear in the file manager as soon as you place the CD into your CD/DVD writer. The file manager lets you transfer files to other computers or perform backups by putting files onto a blank disc. To write files to a CD or DVD. [Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-disc-write.html.en).